# why is my aws glue job uses only one executor and the driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

In my script, I converted all `dynamicframe` to `dataframe` in pyspark, and do the `groupby` and `join` operation. Then in `matrics` view, I found that only one executor is active no matter how many DPU I set.

The job failed after about 2 hours with

> Diagnostics: Container
>   [pid=8417,containerID=container_1532458272694_0001_01_000001] is
>   running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB
>   physical memory used; 7.7 GB of 27.5 GB virtual memory used. Killing
>   container.

I have about 2 billion rows of data. My `DPU` setting is set to 80.

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "in_json", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
datasource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "out_json", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")


applymapping0 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("fieldA", "int", "fieldA", "int"), ("fieldB", "string", "fieldB", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource1, mappings = [("fieldA", "int", "fieldA", "int"), ("fieldB", "string", "fieldB", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

df1 = applymapping0.toDF().groupBy("fieldA"）.agg(count('*').alias("total_number_1"))
df2 = applymapping1.toDF().groupBy("fieldA"）.agg(count('*').alias("total_number_2"))

df1.join(df2, "fieldB")

result = DynamicFrame.fromDF(result_joined, glueContext, "result")

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = result, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://test-bucket"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Does your `DataFrame`  still have column `fieldB` after you have grouped by `fieldA`??

Comment: @botchniaque yes it does. How's that gonna make difference?

Comment: I thought that if you group by one column, you can only access aggregates of different columns. You grouped by `fieldA`, and aggregated as `count(*)`, therefore I thought `fieldB` is not part of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it's because my input data is too large, so it got stuck at the beginning where only one executor is active. Once the calculation begins, I see multiple executors active.

The `df1.repartition(df1("fieldB"))` actually makes it slower, maybe I'm not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try `repartition`ing your `DataFrame`. You can repartition [based on a column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartition-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-), or [to an arbitrary number of partitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartition-int-) or [both](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartition-int-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-).

Something like this:

```
df1 = applymapping0.toDF().groupBy("fieldA"）.agg(count('*').alias("total_number_1"))
df2 = applymapping1.toDF().groupBy("fieldA"）.agg(count('*').alias("total_number_2"))

df1_r = df1.repartition(df1("fieldB"))
df2_r = df2.repartition(df2("fieldB"))

df1_r.join(df2_r, "fieldB")
```